# Cannot connect to phpmyadmin in MAMP

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mamp

when I try to access phpmyadmin on localhost from MAMP I get an error.
It says 
"Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR)) failed: No such file or directory (2)"

This is an error coming out of nowhere. Suddenly it has just stopped working. I can still access the database from other applications like Sequel Pro.

I have tried to search Google to see if other has experinced this error, but I cannot find anything helpful. Hope you can help .

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is reporting that the directory where PHP is trying to store sessions does not exist. This is defined in your PHP configuration by the `session.save_path` directive. Create the directory if necessary and ensure that it has proper permissions so that the webserver process can read and write to it.